# How to permanently remove the ACF plugin from Wordpress, while keeping its functional site?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

hello I want to remove the Advanced custom fields (ACF) plugin on a client's wordpress site in order to switch to another more visual tool for my client (page editor).

When I delete or deactivate the plugin, the site becomes unbrowsable (fatal error that blocks the site).

Is there an effective method to remove ACF from a wordpress site? Should we first go through the deletion of tables in the database, or go into each file to clean the code that uses ACF?

I can't find a tutorial on this subject, which seems trivial and useful to me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Well, a Fatal error is not about the deletion table from the database. A fatal error becomes because of the code, so just uninstall the plugin and remove the code from the template files.

Comment: As you haven't shared the error message you are facing, there's no way to tell you how to resolve if